# OpenGL with Visual C++

Tags: opengl

I created a Visual C++ Project as win32 console setting, and I made a triangle successfully.
I'm using Visual studio 2010.

I wonder why there is no `glOrthof` function but only `glOrtho` function. 
Is that an OpenGL version matter?

I used to use `glOrthof` function when I developed a game on the Android platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OpenGL you only have the one version of [glOrtho](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glOrtho.xml), the one taking floating point values. In Open GL ES there are [two versions](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glOrtho.xml), one taking floats (glOrthof / GLfloat) and one taking fixeds (glOrthox / GLfixed).

One might argu that glOrtho in OpenGL should have the possibility to also use GLdouble, but since glOrtho orgins from back in time when only floats where used and today its depricated/removed there I see no reason to implement that.